# Create a CashRegister class that is used with RetailItem class

Tags: python

Create a CashRegister class that can be used with the RetailItem class.  The CashRegister class should be able to internally keep a list of RetailItem objects.  The class should have the following methods:

•   A method named purchase_item method that accepts a RetailItem object as an argument. Each time the purchase_item method is called, the RetailItem object that is passed as an argement should be added to the list.
•   A method name get_total that returns the total price of all the RetailItem objects stored in the CashRegister object’s internal list.
•   A method name show_items that displays data about the RetailItem objects stored in the CashRegister object’s internal list.
•   A method named clear that should clear the CashRegister object’s internal list.

Demonstrate the CashRegister class in a program that allows the user to select several items for purchase.  When the user is ready to check out, the program should display a list of all the items he or she has selected for purchase, as well as the total price.

```
class RetailItem:

    # The __init__ method initializes the attributes.
    def __init__(self, item, units, price):
        self.__item = item
        self.__units = units
        self.__price = price

    # The following methods are mutators for the class.
    def set_item(self, item):
        self.__item = item
    def set_units(self, units):
        self.__units = units
    def set_price(self, price):
        self.__price = price

    # The following methods are accessors for the class.
    def get_item(self):
        return self.__item
    def get_units(self):
        return self.__units
    def get_price(self):
        return self.__price

    # The __str__ method returns the object's state as a
    #   string.
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Item Description:' + self.__item, \
              '\tNumber of Units:' + self.__units, \
              '\tPrice: $' + self.__price

    # The decrementInventory function decreases the number
    #   units each time called.
    def decrementInventory(units):
        if units > 0:
            units -= 1
        else:
            units = 0
# EOF
```

I believe this RetailItem class is correct and there is no need

```
class CashRegister:

    # The __init__ method initializes the attributes.
    def __init__(self, purchase_item):
        self.__purchase_item = []

    def purchase_item(item, units):
        purchase_item.append(item)
        decrementInventory(units)

    def get_total(price):
        total += price
        return total

    def show_items(item_list):
        for item in item_list:
            print(item.get_item())
            print(item.get_units())
            print(item.get_price())
            print()

    def clear():
        purchase_list [:] = []
# EOF
```

I am not sure if I have this coded properly for the requirements.
Req. A CashRegister object has one attribute, which initialized as an empty list and write the other four methods as previously mentioned.
For the program:
 The main method, create 3 retail objects, then initialize a CashRegister object for the user.  Write a method to display information on the retail items created, (call **str** method).

The following code is what I started with and I am having problems with the four methods from the CashRegister class.

```
import retail_item
import cash_register

SHOW = 1
PURCHASE = 2
CART = 3
TOTAL = 4
EMPTY = 5
QUIT = 6

def main():
    mylist = make_list()
    mycashregister = cash_register.CashRegister(mylist)

    choice = 0

    # Process menu selections until user quits program.
    while choice != QUIT:
        # Get the user's menu choice.
        choice = get_menu_choice()
        # Proces the choice.
        if choice == SHOW:
            __str__(item)
        elif choice == PURCHASE:
            purchase()
        elif choice == CART:
            cart(mycashregister)
        elif choice == TOTAL:
            total(mycashregister)
        elif choice == EMPTY:
            empty(mycashregister)

def make_list():
    item_list = []

    item = 'Jacket'
    units = 12
    price = 59.95
    entry = retail_item.RetailItem(item, units, price)
    item_list.append(entry)

    item = 'Jeans'
    units = 40
    price = 34.95
    entry = retail_item.RetailItem(item, units, price)
    item_list.append(entry)

    item = 'Shirt'
    units = 20
    price = 24.95
    entry = retail_item.RetailItem(item, units, price)
    item_list.append(entry)

    return item_list

# The get_menu_choice function displays the menu and gets
#   a validated choice from the user.
def get_menu_choice():
    print()
    print('CASH REGISTER MENU')
    print('-------------------------')
    print('1. Show Retial Items')
    print('2. Purchase an Item(s)')
    print('3. Show Current Shopping Cart')
    print('4. Show Total of Items Purchased')
    print('5. Empty Your Shopping Cart')
    print('6. Quit the program')
    print()

    # Get the user's choice.
    choice = int(input('Enter your choice: '))

    # Validate the choice.
    while choice < SHOW or choice > QUIT:
        choice = int(input('Enter a valid choice: '))

    # Return the user's choice.
    return choice

def display_list(item_list):
    for item in item_list:
        print('Item Description:', item.get_item(), \
              '\tNumber of Units:', item.get_units(), \
              '\tPrice:', item.get_price())
    print()

def purchase():
    item_purchase = input('Enter the item you wish to purchase: ')

main()
#not EOF more to come if I can figure out the first parts.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: OK, for starters, in your `while` loop in `main()`, you need define the value of `item` somehow. Also, you're going to need to call methods of your `CashRegister` object. i.e. `mycashregister.purchase_item()`, `mycashregister.clear()`, etc, to change its state -- you many need to add some more methods to control and query it. I see your `CashRegister.__init__()` method receives a `purchase_item` argument but doesn't do anything with it, so either it doesn't need the argument or it needs to do something with it. You might want to display a menu of choices before calling `get_menu_choice()`.

Comment: can u help me get started with a method purchase_item that accepts a RetailItem object as an argument.  each time called, the object is passed an as an argument should be added to the list.

Comment: In the `purchase()` function at a minimum you need to call the `mycashregister.purchase_item()` method and pass it the entry in `mylist` that is being purchased. Since it wants to also update the inventory, you could instead pass the whole list to it along with the index of the item being purchased, which would make it possible for it to do the `decrementInventory()`.